# Should this question be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

This question, about reproducing a type of bass sound the asker found in a song, has some upvotes and some close votes.

[Achieve samplepad/keyboard synth sound with a bass guitar for playing live?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24337/achieve-samplepad-keyboard-synth-sound-with-a-bass-guitar-for-playing-live)

The close reason is, questions about identifying a particular instrument are off-topic.

Should it be closed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think the question should be closed. The question does ask how to create a sound the asker found in a song, but I think this is less the asker trying to identify an instrument and more that the asker wants to understand a particular technique (using pedals to make a bass sound like a synth) and is using a particular song as an example. Since the song is an example, the close vote reason doesn't quite apply.

Comment: Totally agree. It's about a technique to produce a sound. It's not apparent that it's useless to future users. Trigger happiness strikes again.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have much to do with 'identifying an instrument' at all. :-/

Comment: I think it's a little bit towards the edge, but still on topic and in scope here.